# I have tried to retrieve `employee info` from javascript object but error while checking javascript console

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

```js
// the Employee object

function Employee( name, email, role ) {
    
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.role = role;

}
    
Employee.prototype.helloEmployee = function() {

    console.log( "Oye" + role);

}

// the emp object inherits from Employee

function emp( name, email ) {

    Employee.call(this, name, email, "admin"); 

}

emp.prototype = Object.create( Employee.prototype );

var kumar = new emp( "Kumar", "info@helloitskumar.com" );

kumar.helloEmployee();
```

I have tried to retrieve `employee info` from javascript object but error while checking javascript console. Can you help what's wrong with my code?

Comment: `console.log( "Oye" + role);` => `console.log( "Oye" + this.role);`

Comment: still getting error http://prntscr.com/h1abox

Comment: Are you serious? )) Sign `=>` just means that you need to replace left value by right value

Comment: Ohh i understand mate
Thanks

Comment: I have already committed.... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Your forgot to add `this` reference in console.log . check this working jsfiddle

```js
// the Employee object

function Employee( name, email, role ) {
    
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.role = role;

}
    
Employee.prototype.helloEmployee = function() {

    console.log( "Oye" + this.role);

}

// the emp object inherits from Employee

function emp( name, email ) {

    Employee.call(this, name, email, "admin"); 

}

emp.prototype = Object.create( Employee.prototype );

var kumar = new emp( "Kumar", "info@helloitskumar.com" );

kumar.helloEmployee();
```